Probability of chain of events over a finite set of event with no repetition
I'm trying to tackle a problem that I suspect resembles others I'm unfamiliar with. I would love pointers for further reading. The problem is as follows:
We have a finite set of actions we can take $\mathcal{A}=\{A_i\}_{i=1}^n$.
We begin with a random variable $ X$ that follows a distribution $ P_x$. We then apply a series of actions, chosen randomly and without repetition, to $ X$ to create a new random variable $ Y$ that follows a distribution $ P_Y$. 
Let $Z_0, \ldots, Z_n$ be the chain of random variables created in the process, where $Z_0=X$ and $Z_n=Y$.
I can compute the transitions probabilities $p(Z_{j}|Z_{j-1},A_i)$.
I'm interested in computing the likelihood $p(Y=y|X=x)$ for a specific pair of observations $(x,y)$.
As the process involves marginalization over all steps and all the permutations of actions, I'm also looking for an estimation process of the likelihood ala Monte-Carlo given that it is easy to sample from $p(Z_{j}|Z_{j-1}, A_i)$.
Do you know if this problem resembles a known one that I can look at? Any other suggestions?
